# Automorphic numbers exercise

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The number 9376 has the peculiar self-reproducing property that
$$9376^{2}=87909376$$

How many 4-digit numbers x satisfy the equation $$x^{2}\equiv x\bmod10000?$$
How many n-digit numbers x satisfy the equation $$x^{2}\equiv x\bmod10^{n}?$$

Answer (score 6):

Since $x$ and $x-1$ are relatively prime, this can only happen when $x-1$ is divisible by $5^n$ and $x$ is divisible by $2^n$, or $x-1$ divisible by $2^n$ and $x$ divisible by $5^n$.

This gives at most two answers, using Chinese Remainder Theorem.

The reason there might be fewer than $2$ is if the solution to the Chinese Remainder Theorem question results in a value less than $10^{n-1}$, and thus is not considered an $n$-digit number. For example, the answers for $n=4$ are $9376$ and $0625$. Depends on whether you call $0625$ a "four digit number. But any number than ends in $0625$, when squared, ends in $0625$.

When $n=5$, you get $90625$ and $09376$. So again, with the usual definition of "$5$-digit number," there is only one answer for $n=5$.

Note that if $x$ is a solution to $$x\equiv 1\pmod{2^n}\\ x\equiv 0\pmod{5^n},$$ then $y=10^n+1-x$ is a solution to $$y\equiv 0\pmod{2^n}\\ y\equiv 1\pmod{5^n}$$

So you only really need to solve one Chinese remainder question, and there will always be at least one $n$-digit number. About one in ten times, there will $2$.

I think it is fairly random whether there is one or two solutions - which would mean you'd expect exactly one solution about one in five $n$. But I'm not sure about that.

(The case were $x$ or $x-1$ is divisible by $10^n$ gives $x\equiv 0,1\pmod{10^n}$ which rarely are counted as an $n$-digit numbers, except when $n=1$. But if we count these - 0001 and 0000 - as four digits, as well, then there are always four answers.)

It's not hard to show that the solutions to:

$$x_n\equiv 0\pmod{5^n}\\ x_n\equiv 1\pmod{2^n}$$

satisfy $x_1=5$, $x_{n+1}\equiv x_n^2\pmod{10^{n+1}}$.

So this means $$x_n\equiv 5^{2^{n-1}}\pmod{10^{n}}$$

The values you get for $x_n$ are:

$$5,25,625,0625,90625, 890625, 2890625, 12890625, 212890625, 8212890625\dots$$

Comment: what about $x=0$ ?

Comment: @mercio It's in my answer. $0$ rarely counts as an $n$-digit number, but if you want to count it, you can count it, and $1$.

Comment: that'll teach me to read the whole thing lol